# Programatticaly Import Pages while Maintaining Hierarchy

Tags: import

I am working on a rather complex import project right now. I'm trying to import 2k pages into Wordpress.  I am able to import them just fine using a tool caleld TurboCSV. The issue is that I also need to maintain hierarchy for the pages. So for example,

```
/about/board-of-directors/page1
```

and

```
/about/members/all-members
```

where `page1` and `all-members` are pages, that have parents of "board of directors" and "members" (which in tern have parent pages of "about".

Parent pages are set by page ID in the database, so I'm not sure how programmatically importing these would be possible because it would require first creating the page before assigning the parent ID. But I wanted to see if anyone has any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee the "uniqueness" of each page's title, I would first run the entire import, and *then* loop over the newly inserted pages & set their parents by cross referencing the CSV.

Comment: Ah ha!  That's a great idea.  I think this just might work with a little vlookup trickery. Thank you!!